# Extend mutually recursive functors

Tags: recursion, ocaml, functor

I am writing a compiler and need to represent several structures that are co recursive and depend on the data-structure representing expressions. At the beginning of compilation my expressions are not typed but I do type them at a later stage.

I wrote the following functors to be able to reuse code during the process:

```
module type Exp = sig                                                                                                                  
  type t                                                                                                                               
end  

module type IR = sig                                                                                                                    
  type exp                                                                                                                              
  type ty =                                                                                                                             
    | Unknown                                                                                                                           
    | Typed of exp                                                                                                                      
  type exp_descr =                                                                                                                      
    | Leaf                                                                                                                              
    | Node of exp                                                                                                                       
end                                                                                                                                     

module MyIR (E: Exp) = struct                                                                                                           
  type ty =                                                                                                                             
    | Unknown                                                                                                                           
    | Typed of E.t                                                                                                                      

  type exp_descr =
    | Leaf 
    | Node of E.t

  type exp = E.t  
end       

module UntypedExp (TD: IR) : (Exp with type t = TD.exp_descr) = struct
  type t = TD.exp_descr
end                          

module TypedExp (TD: IR) : Exp = struct
  type t =        
    {
      ty : TD.ty; 
      descr : TD.exp_descr;
    }            
end

module rec UTExp : Exp = UntypedExp(UTIR)
and UTIR : IR = MyIR(UTExp)

module rec TExp : Exp = TypedExp(TIR)
and TIR : IR = MyIR(TExp)
```

I now have 2 intermediate representations one that uses untyped expressions and the other that uses typed expressions.

I now want to write a printing module and I want to factorize code in the same manner as I did earlier. Below is my unsuccessful attempt, I don't understand how properly extend `TExp` and `UTexp`.
More specifically, I don't know how to share the field constructor defined in `TypedExp`.

```
module type ExpPrint = sig             
  type t  
  val string_of_t: t -> string
end              

module type IRPrint = sig
  include IR
  val string_of_ty: ty -> string
  val string_of_exp_descr: exp_descr -> string
  val string_of_exp: exp -> string
end

module MyExpPrint (R: IR) (E: ExpPrint with type t = R.exp) : (IRPrint with type exp := R.exp and type exp_descr := R.exp_descr and type ty := R.ty) = struct
  open R
  let string_of_exp = E.string_of_t
  let string_of_ty = function
    | R.Unknown -> "Unknown"
    |   Typed e -> "Typed: " ^ string_of_exp e

  let string_of_exp_descr = function
    | R.Leaf   -> "Leaf"
    |   Node e -> "Node: " ^ string_of_exp e

end

module UTExpPrint (E : module type of UTExp) (R: IRPrint with type exp = E.t) : (ExpPrint with type t := R.exp_descr) = struct
  open E
  let string_of_t = R.string_of_exp_descr
end

module TExpPrint (E : module type of TExp) (R: IRPrint with type exp = E.t) : (ExpPrint with type t := R.exp) = struct
  open E
  let string_of_t e = R.string_of_exp_descr e.TExp.descr ^ " " ^ R.string_of_ty e.ty
end
```

EDIT: fixes the problems with `MyExpPrint`

Comment: I also had a very similar problem, it might also be helpful to reference the answer on my thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/52359942/5055063

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the module type `Exp` is defined as

```
 module type Exp = sig type t end
```

any signature constraint of the form `M: Exp` makes `M` unusable since it hides all information about M, except the existence of an abstract type M.t. This abstract type is unusable since there are no functions between this type and the outside world.

For instance, this module definition defines a type and immediately hides it to the outside world:

```
module TypedExp (TD: IR) : Exp = struct
  type t =        
    {
    ty : TD.ty; 
    descr : TD.exp_descr;
   }            
end
```

What you wanted was simply

```
module TypedExp (TD: IR) = struct
  type t =        
    {
    ty : TD.ty; 
    descr : TD.exp_descr;
   }            
end
```

If you really want to add a signature constraint, the right one would be

```
module TypedExp (TD: IR): sig
  type t =        
    {
    ty : TD.ty; 
    descr : TD.exp_descr;
   }            
end
= struct
  type t =        
    {
    ty : TD.ty; 
    descr : TD.exp_descr;
   }            
end
```

Note that that I did not use `Exp with type t = ...` for two reasons: First, the `with` constraint cannot define new types. Second, `Exp with type t = ...` is just a complicated way to write `sig type t = ... end`.

This is the core issue with your code: it is hiding all information that would make possible to manipulate meaningfully the type that you defines.

For instance, after removing the signature constraint on functor result, fixing the signature in the recursive module constraints, simplifying the signature of IRprint to

```
module type IRPrint = sig
  type ty
  type exp_descr
  type exp
  val string_of_ty: ty -> string
  val string_of_exp_descr: exp_descr -> string
  val string_of_exp: exp -> string
end
```

then the functor `TExpPrint` can be fixed with

```
module TExpPrint
    (E : module type of TExp)
    (R: IRPrint with type exp_descr = TIR.exp_descr
                 and type exp = E.t
                 and type ty = TIR.ty)
=
struct
  open E
  let string_of_t e =
    R.string_of_exp_descr e.E.descr ^ " " ^ R.string_of_ty e.ty
end
```

and I expect the rest of the errors to follow since it becomes possible to share the right type equalities.